# Propel to Doctrine Code Snippet

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony-1.4, propel

I am using symfony 1.4 with Doctrine ORM. I am editing some of the actions, and I need to rewrite a Propel query into Doctrine. Here's the snippet:

```
  $c = new Criteria();
  $c->add(BlogCommentPeer::BLOG_POST_ID, $request->getParameter('id'));
  $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(BlogCommentPeer::CREATED_AT);
  $this->comments = BlogCommentPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Can anyone help with the conversion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BlogCommentTable.php` file, put this method :

```
public functoion retrieveByPostId($post_id)
{
  $q = $this->createQuery('c')
    ->where('c.blog_post_id = ?', array($post_id))
    ->orderBy('c.created_at ASC');

  return $q->execute();
}
```

And in your action:

```
$this->comments = Doctrine_Core::getTable('BlogComment')->retrieveByPostId($request->getParameter('id'));
```

Comment: oops. sorry. kinda new to this and still figuring out the rules of engagement.